# needs someone to

Tags: infinitives, ambiguity

a. He needs a wife to overcome his alcoholism.

b. He wants a wife to overcome his alcoholism.

=============================

c. He needs someone to overcome his alcoholism.

d. He wants someone to overcome his alcoholism.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

In each case he is the one who is overcoming his alcoholism. In (c) and (d) he needs someone's help.

I don't think (d) really works.

Comment: All of the sentences are grammatically correct but semantically and practically wrong. "He needs somebody to help him overcome his alcoholism"

Comment: Thank you very much. How about 'He needs someone in order to overcome his alcoholism'?

Comment: nope. "needing a person" is when you want the person. "needing a person **to xxxx**"  is when you want xxxx.  "needing a person **in order to xxxx**" is when you think that, when you get the person, you will automatically get xxxx. The way that we describe things affects the way that we think about them: people who don't see a distinction between these expressions, usually end up making things worse for everybody.